# java.sql.SQLException: Field foreign_key doesn't have a default value

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, foreign-keys

I have following model structure:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TEMPLATE")
public class MyTemplate {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MY_TEMPLATE_ID")
    private List<MyObject> myobjects = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_OBJECT")
public class MyObject implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
}
```

`MyDailyResource` doesn't have reference to `MyTemplate`

I have also usual `CrudRepository`:

```
public interface MyTemplateRepository extends CrudRepository<MyTemplate, Long> {
}
```

When I execute:

`myTemplateRepo.save(myTemplate)` // myTemplate has one element in myObjects collection

I see following error:

```
    insert 
    into
        MY_TEMPLATE
        (LAST_MODIFIED, LAST_MODIFIED_BY, NAME) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?)


    insert 
    into
        MY_OBJECT
        (BAR, FOO) 
    values
        (?, ?)

java.sql.SQLException: Field 'MY_TEMPLATE_ID' doesn't have a default value
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
```

I have no ideas what do I wrong and how to fix it.

Could you, please, recommend me something?

### P.S.

Looks like it is because I have not null constraint for that foreign key in database. But I don't like to remove that constraint

Comment: which one is your parent table

Answer (score 0):

Hope your parent table is MY_TEMPLATE and child table is MY_OBJECT

updating you classes

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TEMPLATE")
public class MyTemplate {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="myTemplate", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<MyObject> myObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_OBJECT")
public class MyObject implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "MY_TEMPLATE_ID")
    private MyTemplate myTemplate;
}
```

Comment: Please share the table script.